# Maximum call stack size exceeded error in asynchronous function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a function that takes endpoint and returns the JSON result of a GET request to this endpoint

Here is my code

```js
const baseUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/'

const endpoints = {
    users: 'users',
    posts: 'posts',
}

const getData = async endpoint => {
    const response = await fetch(baseUrl + endpoint)
    if (!response.ok) return response.statusText

    const data = await response.json()
    return data
}

var user, posts

const fetch = async () =>
    await getData(endpoints.users).then(data => {
        user = data
    })

console.log(fetch())
```

When I compile it I get

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: Your `fetch()` immediately calls `getData()`, and `getData()` immediately calls `fetch()`, in an infinite loop, what are you expecting to happen here? (Is your `fetch` function perhaps accidentally overwriting the function from the built in fetch API?)

Comment: @DBS Oh yes that was an accident, I was testing and chose a worst name for it, thanks!